# Expected a value of type 'int', but got one of type 'String'

Tags: api, flutter

estoy trabajando con esta api: https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime
lo que quiero es obtener tanto las peliculas(imagenes) como sus titulos. antes solo estaba mostrando las imagenes dentro de un listview.builder horizontal y todo iba de maravilla. pero al querer poner sus respectivos titulos debajo de cada imagen obtuve el error mencionado en el titulo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
final list = data['data'] as List;
      //final list = data['data']["title"] as List;
      //return list.map((e) => DataApi(image: e)).toList();
      return list
          .map((e) => DataApi(
              image: e["images"]["jpg"]["image_url"],
              title: e["titles"]["title"]))
          .toList();
```

la forma en que pretendo mostrarlos.

```
if (snapshot.hasData) {
          final lista = snapshot.data!;
          return Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20),
            child: Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height: 200,
              child: ListView.builder(
                scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                itemCount: lista.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return Column(
                    children: [
                      Image.network(
                        lista[index].image,
                      ),
                      Text(lista[index].title),
                    ],
                  );
                },
              ),
```

como dije lo que pretendo es poner cada nombre de la pelicula debajo de su imagen.
porfavor les agradeceria mucho. gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Revisé el API y en esta linea

```
title: e["titles"]["title"]))
```

estás accediendo de manera erronea al titulo. Estás accediendo a

```
e["titles"]["title"])) es un arreglo que contiene otros objetos con la siguiente estructura 
                {
                    "type": "Default",
                    "title": "Cowboy Bebop"
                },
Si deseas acceder a un titulo de esta lista debes usar el index  e["titles"][0]["title"]))
```

Por otro lado, creo que quieres acceder al titulo que se encuentra en un nivel anterior, lo harías de la siguiente manera.

```
class DataApi{
   String? image = '';
   String? title = ''; 
  DataApi(
    {this.image, this.title});
}
getData() async{
  final uri = Uri.parse('https://api.jikan.moe/v4/anime');
var response = await http.get(uri);
print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
 final decodedData = json.decode(response.body);
final list = decodedData['data'] as List;
  final newList = list.map(
  (e) => new DataApi(
     image: e["images"]["jpg"]["image_url"],
    title: e["title"]
  )
  ).toList();
  
  for(var element in newList){
    print(element.image);
    print(element.title);
  }
}
```

El for únicamente es para que revises que estas accediendo a los elementos de forma correcta.

Comment: te lo agradezco mucho gracias

Comment: no comprendo porque me muestra todos los nombres si al añadir [0] estaria accediendo solo a la pelicula de ese valor no? tengo dudas porfavor

Comment: En el último for hacemos un recorrido de todas las películas que devuelve el API en este caso 25, si quisieras imprimir solo la primera  película lo harías con print(newList[0].title), 
cuando estás agregando el titulo con e["titles"][0]["title"], estas tomando el primer valor de la lista "titles" de cada película. (Pero igual se siguen agregando las mismas 25, solo que cada una tiene una lista de hasta 3 nombres diferentes.)
Te sugiero utilizar POSTMAN para tener un preview de la respuesta de tu API de manera que puedas comprender mejor la estructura de la respuesta.